# Interpolation from polygons to polygons

Tags: arcgis-desktop, interpolation

In a country I have numeric data by province, but not for all the provinces. With arcgis I would like to interpolate those data to the no-data provinces. Of course I have administrative georeferenced shapefiles.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 2):

ESRI implemented **Areal Interpolatio**n for that in the **Geostatistical Analyst**:

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/geostatistical-analyst/what-is-areal-interpolation.htm

This should give you a statistically sound result.

Comment: Someone knows whether there is a similar tool for Qgis?